# Angular Material Paginator not working with async data

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-material2, ngrx

I have an Angular Material Data Table and I am trying to add pagination to it.

I have come across this problem that if the data is an async source then Mat-Paginator doesn't work.

I tried with Sync source and Pagination works as expected but as I have an observable the pagination does not get initialized when the data finally arrives.

However, I have tried searching for this problem and so far no one seems to be having this problem so it may be down to my setup.

Following is my ts file for my component.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, style, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Country} from '../../core/models/country';
import { OnChanges, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'app-country-list',
    templateUrl: './country-preview-list.html',
    styleUrls : ['./country-preview-list.css']
})
export class CountryListComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
    @Input() public countries: Country[];
    displayedColumns = ['Name', 'Code'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Country>;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Country>(this.countries);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }

}
```

and Parent component html has this line to add my component

```
<app-country-list [countries]="countries$ | async"></app-country-list>
```

**Edit**

**Parent Component TS file**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

import * as fromCountries from '../../state/countries/reducers';
import * as fromConfiguration from '../../state/configuration/reducers';
import * as country from '../../state/countries/actions/countries';
import * as configuration from '../../state/configuration/actions/configuration';
import { Country} from '../../core/models/country';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countries-page',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <app-country-search (searchCountries)="search($event)"></app-country-search>
    <app-country-list [countries]="countries$ | async"></app-country-list>
  `,
})
export class CountriesPageComponent {
  countries$: Observable<Country[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromCountries.State>) {
    this.countries$ = store.pipe(select(fromCountries.getAllCountries));
  }

  search(query: any) {
    this.store.dispatch(new country.Search(query));
  }

}
```

if change countries$ | async to a synchronous list of countries; paginator works.

Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, there is no Observable (of any type) named `countries$` in the component. Is this all the code you have?

Comment: Have you tried moving `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` to the end of `ngOnChanges()` ? Since you create a new datasource, its `paginator` property is reset. You could also try simply setting the datasource's data (using `this.dataSource.data`) directly.

Comment: @R. Richards I'm guessing `countries$` is defined in the parent component's script. Having the complete code (or even better, a StackBlitz) would definitely help though.

Comment: @Jeto You're right! That is where that would live. Agreed, we need to see more.

Comment: @Jeto - yes you guessed it right; countries$ is defined in the parent component. I will try to create a StackBlitz. In the mean time I am editing and adding the parent component ts file in the my question. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Jeto - I moved this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; to the end of ngOnChanges() but result still the same. It appears that paginator is somehow remains disconnected from the datasource. I will try to extract my code and make a StackBlitz; Thanks

Comment: @Robert Dinaro What about changing `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Country>(this.countries);` to `this.dataSource.data = this.countries;`? (Did you check that `ngOnChanges` is called?)

Comment: Now that we can see that ngrx is in the mix, the StackBlitz will go a long way.

Comment: I have found out why it is acting as if paginator is disconnected. I tried to log it to console and it comes back as undefined. Your idea about StackBlitz was good as html code was hidden. I have the data table and paginator inside an ngIf and when the ViewChild tries to read paginator; it is not there so it remains undefined. Need to figure out how to keep it hidden until data arrives but at the same time - don't let it be undefined.

Comment: Roberto. Check where is <mat-paginator> in you html and what mechanism are you using between view and backend to be in sync. For example use boolean variable which is false when data is processing and then set to true at the end. And later in you html use :
*ngIf="variable" or *ngIf="!variable".
<div *ngIf="!variable">
<mat-spinner>Loading<mat-spinner>
</div>
<div>
<table *ngIf="variable" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
</table> 
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
</div>

Answer (score 11):

Your last comment help me find the solution to this. This is indeed caused by the fact that the dataTable is inside a ngIf*.

The issue is described [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10205) in more detail.

To solve the problem remove this code:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

and add this:

```
private paginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
  this.paginator = mp;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Comment: An entire day on it (－‸ლ)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a loading(async) then after loading you need to render the table and set the paginate async. try this

component.html

```html
<loading-component *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></loading-component> <--WHILE Loading

<div *ngIf="!(isLoading$ | async)"> <-- AFTER Loading
    <ng-container *ngIf="dataSource.data.length >= 1; else noData">  <--Check if there's data
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            ...
        </table>
 <mat-paginator></mat-paginator>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #noData>  <- In case there is not data (to not show the table/table-header)
        ...
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class Component {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;  
  private _paginator: MatPaginator;
  
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) { <--SET you can fetch (async)
    this._paginator = mp;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this._paginator;
  }
  .. the rest of the component logic ...
```

With the SET you can fetch async data to table and then paginate it.

Keep coding \m/